# A question regarding partition of positive integers.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

> > For a given partition $T$ of a positive integer $n$, let $g_{T,n}$ denote the number of distinct parts in $T$ and let $h_{T,n}$ denote the number of $1$'s appearing as parts in $T$. Let $$p_1(n) = \sum \limits_{T} h_{T,n}$$ and $$p_{p} (n) = \sum \limits_{T} g_{T,n}.$$ Where $T$ varies over all the partitions of $n$.
> >
> > Show that, for any positive integer $n$, $p_{1} (n) = p_{p} (n)$.

How do I proceed to prove it? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

**EDIT** $:$

I have found that $p_{1} (n) = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n-1} P(k)$ where $P(k)$ is the partition function evaluated at $k$.

Comment: You mean, $p_1(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}P(k)$ surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, $p_1(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}P(k)$. I'll show the same holds for
$p_p(n)$.

Now $p_p(n)=q_1(n)+q_2(n)+\cdots+q_n(n)$ where $q_k(n)$ is the number
of partitions of $n$ having $k$ as a part. But removing $k$ as a part from
a partition of $n$ having $k$ as a part yields a partition of $n-k$.
Each partition of $n-k$ arises exactly once in this way. Therefore,
$q_k(n)=P(n-k)$, and
$$p_p(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n P(n-k)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}P(k).$$

Comment: What is $P(0)$? Is $P(0) = 0$? I have written $p_1(n) = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n-1} P(k) \neq \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-1} P(k)$ unless $P(0)=0$.

Comment: If $P(k)$ is the "partition function evaluated at $k$", then $P(0)$ is the "partition function evaluated at $0$": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function

Comment: "$p_1(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}P(k)$" is incorrect. In fact, $p_1(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}P(k)$.

Comment: Then your result and my result differ by $1$. They don't match.

Comment: The number of partitions of $n$ with at least one $1$ is $P(n-1)$, the number of partitions of $n$ with at least two $1$'s is $P(n-2)$, Continuing this argument using induction we have the number of partitions of $n$ with at least $(n-1)$ $1$'s is $P(1)$ and the number of partitions of $n$ with $n$ $1$'s is $P(0)$. So you are correct. $p_1 (n) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} P(k)$.

Comment: Please check my argument above?

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Your argument is correct. Now how about an up-vote?  $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Oh! You want reputation. Right? Ok. I am going to upvote your answer because it is helpful. Please wait for a minute till the system shows it.